# ggplot2 geom_boxplot: cannot remove x-axis tics and text

Tags: r, ggplot2

All references to removing axis tics and text say to change the theme's elements to blank. It's not working for me. Here's an example:

```
p2 <- ggplot(data = sal_pH, aes(x = NULL, y = quant)) +
    stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.3) + 
    geom_boxplot(# custom boxes
        color='#00008B',
        fill='#00008B',
        alpha=0.4,
        # custom outliers
        outlier.color='blue1',
        outlier.fill='white',
        outlier.size=2) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_classic(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
    xlab('Salem') +
    ylab('pH') +
    ylim(6.0, 10.0)
```

R throws this error:

```
Error in theme_classic(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) (from all_pH_plots.r#30) : 
  unused arguments (axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

Is there a way to remove x-axis tics and text using the classic theme?

Comment: Try with `theme_classic() + theme(axis.text.x = ....)`.

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of your data using `dput(sal_PH)`? We can't recreate your plot to help otherwise

Comment: Maybe try ```... theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) + ...```

Comment: That's what I first did when the error appeared. That's why I combined the two theme() options.

Comment: site_nbr,sampdate,param,quant,unit
31731,2005-07-12,pH,7.60,valueless
31731,2007-03-28,pH,6.90,valueless
31731,2007-06-27,pH,7.90,valueless
31731,2007-09-26,pH,7.70,valueless
31731,2008-01-17,pH,6.70,valueless
31731,2008-03-27,pH,7.40,valueless
31731,2010-04-05,pH,7.20,valueless
31731,2010-04-05,pH,7.50,valueless
31731,2010-07-26,pH,7.50,valueless
31731,2010-10-18,pH,7.20,valueless
31731,2011-01-10,pH,7.30,valueless

Comment: By trial-and-error I've learned that one can remove axis tics and text only with the default theme. Both theme_classic and theme_bw will not allow me to remove the x-axis tics or text. Why these attributes are restricted to a theme type makes no sense to me, but that's the way it is. Sigh. They'll have to stay on the plots even though they're meaningless and can confuse a viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at `theme_classic`'s source we can see that is a custom call to `theme` and `theme_bw`. We can add `axis.text.x=element_blank()` and `axis.ticks.x=element_blank()` and the ticks are removed. I used `mtcars` dataset as dummy data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

theme_classic_custom <- function(base_size = 11, base_family = "", base_line_size = base_size / 22,
                                 base_rect_size = base_size / 22) {
  theme_bw(
    base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family,
    base_line_size = base_line_size, base_rect_size = base_rect_size
  ) %+replace%
    theme(
      panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
      axis.line = element_line(
        colour = "black",
        size = rel(1)
      ), legend.key = element_blank(),
      strip.background = element_rect(
        fill = "white", colour = "black",
        size = rel(2)
      ), complete = TRUE
    )
}


as_tibble(mtcars) %>% 
 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  theme_classic_custom() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: jpdugo17: I correctly copied your code but it's not working in my script. I'm working with client data and would like to contact you directly so I can learn why it's not working here.